# While loop keeps looping without intent going trough

Tags: kotlin, android-intent, while-loop

What I need to happen is as follow:

1. Start loop
2. I need to have the intent go to the class to get a result
3. Result will be one of two things, were both are needed to exit the while loop.
4. Exit loop

Code:

```
        while ( plate == "0" ||  location == "0"){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Starting scan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intent = Intent(this, LocationScan::class.java)

            // 0 is request code
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0)}
```

What happens currently is the screen flashes and `Toast` keeps displaying. Intent does not load. Disabling loop takes me to intent and displays result.

`plate` and `location` is changed by the result of `LocationScan`. Result is received by :

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the result from intent
                val result = intent.getStringExtra("result")

                if (result!![0] in 'a'..'z' || result!![0] in 'A'..'Z'){
                    location = result

                    println("$result is an location.")}
                else{
                    plate = result

                    println("$result is a plate.")}

            } } }
```

*Compile Sdk : 33*   *Gradle Version : 7.4*  *Android Gradle Version :7.3.1* *Java : 1.8*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing/suspending the current Activity to open a new one requires the main thread to do a bunch of work, including calling `onPause` in this Activity. So calling `startActivityForResult` won't create the new Activity *immediately*, it'll schedule the transition for the future.

And it can't carry that transition out while you're blocking the main thread spinning on a loop. Even if it *did* immediately interrupt execution, it wouldn't return to the same point in your code (you're even relying on it calling `onActivityResult` instead). Activities and Fragments just don't work like that.

---

What you probably want to do instead, is have a function that checks your conditions. If they're not met, call `startActivityForResult` and let execution continue. Then in `onActivityResult`, handle the result and then **call the checking function again**. If the conditions *still* aren't met, it'll start the Activity again, `onActivityResult` will be called again, the checking function will run again...

So this way, you're creating a cycle that runs through the Activity system and its callbacks - it's still looping behaviour, but it's not an actual execution loop, if you see what I mean. You're effectively putting the task back on the queue until everything's taken care of, instead of blocking the thread.

Comment: Thank you for this answer explaing why it is happening and what is the right why to do it. This is the first time I encounter something like this. So thank you for educating me.  •ᴗ•